# Component re-rendering in arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have an arrow function to toggle a div and set a button to either show or be hidden based upon the div.

```
    toggleDeliveryDiv = () => {
        document.getElementById('btn_collapse_delivery').click(); 
        this.setState({deliveryShow: !this.state.deliveryShow})
        
        var styl = document.getElementById("plusDiv")
     
            if(this.state.deliveryShow){
                styl.style.display = 'block'
            }else{
                styl.style.display = 'none'
            }
    }
```

and i call the arrow function in an onClick event like this:

```
onClick={this.toggleDeliveryDiv}
```

But the method is either called twice or the component is re-rendered as a result of the setState call, i guess. Please how can i prevent the re-rendering in the arrow function or how better can i achieve this ???

Comment: You should not actively manipulate the DOM in react (unless in very specific corner cases), you should rely on `this.state` to change visibility.

Comment: My use case deprives me the ability to rely on state to change visibility as it always creates a new instance and causes a multiple element with same id error

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'this.state.deliveryShow' to change the style for your div element rather than manipulating the DOM. This way you wouldn't have to handle it manually.

```
<div id="plusDiv" style={{display:this.state.deliveryShow?'block':'none'}}></div>
```

Comment: Both methods still causes a re-render or multiple function call

Comment: I have edited the answer accordingly. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although i am still having same issue i had while using state to control style. So the button I am trying to hide or show I an add button that dynamically adds an extra form component. Currently when the button is clicked the the extra component is added but entire div is also toggled.
Add method:
```
    addChild = (e) => {
        let objId = e.target.id; let objName = "text"+objId;
        e.target.id = Number(objId) + 1
        var objCom = this.state.componentList.concat({id:objId,name:objName,booleane:true})
     this.setState({ componentList: objCom })
  }

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:
`onClick={this.toggleDeliveryDiv}`
or
`onClick={()=>this.toggleDeliveryDiv()}`